# Unable to get modification context for Active Directory records through Spring LDAP

Tags: spring, active-directory, spring-ldap

I am trying to use Spring LDAP to retrieve and modify user information in an Active Directory server, but I can't retrieve a user record by dn so that I can modify it.

I am able to find the record by username with the `LdapTemplate.search` method.  There is no `dn` attribute in the record, but `distinguishedName` looks like it should be correct.  When I use `LdapTemplate.lookupContext` to retrieve the record by dn, however, the server says that it can't find the record by the `dn` that it just gave me.  What am I doing wrong?

It seem wrong that the `LdapTemplate` search method doesn't give you a handle that you can use without doing a second query from the Active Directory.  Is there a better way to do this?

I have created a sample Groovy application to demonstrate the problem.  My Spring Boot application creates this class and then invokes the runTest method.

```
package edu.sunyjcc.gateway.ldap;

import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import static org.springframework.ldap.query.LdapQueryBuilder.query;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;

public class ActiveDirectoryDNSample {

  LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

  /** Attributes to fetch from server */
  static attributeList = [
    "sAMAccountName",
    "distinguishedName",
    "baseDn",
    "userPrincipalName",
  ];

  /** This will represent the record retrieved from Active Directory */
  class Person {
    /** Raw data from server */
    Map attributes = [:];
    /** Return the distinguished name */
    String getDn() {
      attributes?.distinguishedName;
    }
    String getUsername() {
      attributes?.sAMAccountName;
    }
    String toString() {
      "${this.username} <${this.getDn()}>"
    }
    /** Get a handle to the object from AD so we can modify it.  This fails. */
    def getContext() {
      assert ldapTemplate;
      println "in getContext()";
      def dn = new LdapName(this.getDn());
      println "...dn=$dn"
      assert dn;
      // The next line throws an exception.
      DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);
      println "...context=$context"
    }
  }

  /** Convert the attributes from AD into a Person object */
  class RecordMapper implements AttributesMapper<Person> {

    /** Create a Person object from the attribute map */
    Person mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes)
    throws NamingException {
      assert ldapTemplate;
      Person prec = new Person(
        ldapTemplate: ldapTemplate
      );
      attributeList.collect {
        [attrName: it, attr: attributes.get(it)]
      }.grep {it.attr}.each {
        prec.attributes."${it.attrName}" = it.attr.get() as String;
      }
      return prec;
    }
  }

  /** Get a user from Active Directory */
  public List<Person> getByUsername(String username) throws Exception {
    assert ldapTemplate;
    AttributesMapper attrMapper = new RecordMapper();
    assert attrMapper;
    List s = ldapTemplate.search(
      query().
      where("sAMAccountName").is(username),
      attrMapper
    );
    if (s == null) {
      System.err.println("s is null");
    }
    return s?:[];
  }

  /** Try to fetch a record and get a modify context for it */
  public runTest(String username) {
    println "In ActiveDirectoryDNSample.runText($username)"
    assert ldapTemplate;
    def records = getByUsername(username);
    println "Retrieved ${records?.size()} records";
    records.each {println "   $it"}
    println "Now try to get the context for the records"
    records.each {
      person ->
      println "    getting context for $person";
      def context = person.getContext();
      println "      context=$context"
    }
  }


  public ActiveDirectoryDNSample(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate ) {
    this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
  }
}

In ActiveDirectoryDNSample.runText(testuser)
Retrieved 1 records
   testuser <CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=jccadmin,DC=sunyjcc,DC=edu>
Now try to get the context for the records
    getting context for testuser <CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=jccadmin,DC=sunyjcc,DC=edu>
in getContext()
...dn=CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=jccadmin,DC=sunyjcc,DC=edu
```

and then it dies with a `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` with the following data.

```
[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=Users,DC=jccadmin,DC=sunyjcc,DC=edu'
\0]
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was, indeed, a better way.  Instead of using an `org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper` in the search, you use `org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextMapper`.

In my example, I added a field to the Person class, which will hold a reference to the context.

```
DirContextOperations context;
```

Then I created a new class extending `org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextMapper`.

```
class PersonContextMapper extends AbstractContextMapper  {
  @Override
  protected Object doMapFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx) {
    AttributesMapper attrMapper = new RecordMapper();
    Person p = attrMapper.mapFromAttributes(ctx.attributes);
    p.context = ctx;
    return p;
  }
}
```

When I passed it to the `ldapTemplate.search` method in the place of the `AttributeMapper`, I was able to use the context to update the Active Directory.